# Retrieving multiple rows from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

I would like to know the best way to approach this problem.  I want to search multiple sheets of data based on customerid and retrieve data from each sheet such as customer address(es), customer order(s), customer personal information, etc.

Options off top of my head is...

1. Filter Pivot Tables by customer but would I do that automatically for all sheets?
2. vlookup data into one sheet based on customer search term
3. Is there a way to use an SQL-type command to query data from sheets and display?

I would like to retrieve similar to a SQL query but without use of macros.  I don't see a way to retrieve data from these different tables in an automated fashion.

Comment: Your best bet is a dropdown of available customers and vlookups for every field you want to retrieve.

Comment: Are all of the sheets in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup basically falls apart the moment you multiple data sets for the same key (for example, 10 order rows for 1 cust_id) unless you make some kind of complex formula to get all of the items and predict how many you need.

I've used 2 solutions for this kind of problem:

1: Several pivot tables on the same sheet, each linked to their respective tables. Unfortunately, the user has to select the same filter for each one as needed. This is still the cleanest solution and I recommend it.

2: Make a translation table (sheet) that glues all of the other tables together. 
Each cell just points to the other sheet. Pivot this

For example, if you have table 1 as ID, NAME, ADDRESS and Table 2 as ID, ORDER you might end up with a giant sheet of formulas:

A1 as =Names!A1 
A2 as = Names!A2

B1 as =Vlookup(Orders!A1...)

Fill down as needed.. use formulas on this sheet to link the data as needed. You're basically simulating SQL table joins and yes it is a pain but can be done! =) Provided any of this works for your data sets, in theory you could then make 1 large pivot table.